# Effective way to develop scheduling apps both on web and android

Tags: android, codeigniter, web-services

Im currently studying to develop a schedule apps project.. This app developed both on web and android.. Warn: This post will be long with some newbie questions inside

So, the Main features are: the app interface like a calendar with addable reminders and activity.. (like google calendar)

The only thing i could think firstly is build a restServer along with the client, so my android app could connect to the same database.. My progress right now is developing the restServer with codeigniter..

Before going to far i decide to ask this on the forum to get any ideas.

The problem is i dont know what should i do to make them integrated to each other.. If im using library (ex: the calendar to track reminders and activity) on the website.. So how i implement that to my android app too? I know how to get the data.. But how about the ui?

Could i use any library for calendar on android and implement same data as on the website?

And then, what is the effective way to implement this project? I tried to search something like progressive web apps but no luck.. Hard to find the tutorial..

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.. This is my first post, very sorry for any mistakes and my bad grammar

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is too broad. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh im sorry.. Will have a look at the given link.. Should i recreate this post?

Comment: Most likely you can edit it.